# Проблемы с распаковкой архива в Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, архивация

В Windows 10  после установки Java возникают следующие проблемы с распаковкой архива src, входящего в jdk:

1. Штатный распаковщик Windows заявляет: "Компоненту сжатые zip-папки не удалось создать указанный каталог. Убедитесь, что каталог еще не существует и что путь введен правильно".
2. 7-zip все распаковывает и в его менеджере созданная папка распакованного архива отображается, но проводник Windows все равно ее не показывает.  Распакованный архив можно удалить из менеджера 7-zip и он прекрасно находится в корзине. После его восстановления из корзины он наконец становится доступным в проводнике Windows.
3. При желании, эксперименты можно продолжить. Например, распаковываем все тот же архив при помощи 7-zip. Распаковываем его еще раз в папку с другим именем. Проводник Windows, естественно ни одну из них не видит. Удаляем одну из папок из менеджера 7-zip и восстанавливаем ее из архива. Проводник ее видит. Переименовываем ее точно в такую же, которая создана в менеджере 7-zip. Никто ни на что не ругается. Заходим в менеджер 7-zip. Он показывает только одну папку с таким именем. Удаляем ее. Папка удаляется, но тут же на ее месте появляется одноименная. Удаляем и ее. Таких папок больше нет. Заходим в корзину - обе папки с одинаковым именем имеются в наличии.

Как объяснить все эти чудеса?

**Обновление**

В принципе, понятно, что проблема лежит в области доступа к папке, находящейся в Program files (хотя права администраторские). Но почему все так накручено? Ну например, создать файл и сохранить его в папке, находящейся в Program files система не позволяет, а создать, сохранить на рабочем столе, а потом переместить во все ту же папку можно? Ну или все то же сделать с архивом.

Answer (score 1):

По вашему описанию два варианта, либо вы запускаете установку ява без прав администратора, либо на пк присутствует нежелательное по.

Саму установку программы нужно принудительно запускать от имени администратора, тогда проблем не будет. Правой кнопкой мыши по установщику ---> запустить от имени администратора.